# What is the difference between building cypher and executing the prepared statement in the following code

Tags: python, apache-age

I am unable to understand why there are two queries being executed. First we are executing the prepared statement and we are using the build cypher function. The code can be found here
https://github.com/apache/age/blob/master/drivers/python/age/age.py

```
def execCypher(conn:ext.connection, graphName:str, cypherStmt:str, cols:list=None, params:tuple=None) -> ext.cursor :
    if conn == None or conn.closed:
        raise _EXCEPTION_NoConnection

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    #clean up the string for modification
    cypherStmt = cypherStmt.replace("\n", "")
    cypherStmt = cypherStmt.replace("\t", "")
    cypher = str(cursor.mogrify(cypherStmt, params))
    cypher = cypher[2:len(cypher)-1]

    preparedStmt = "SELECT * FROM age_prepare_cypher({graphName},{cypherStmt})"
    
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute(sql.SQL(preparedStmt).format(graphName=sql.Literal(graphName),cypherStmt=sql.Literal(cypher)))
    except SyntaxError as cause:
        conn.rollback()
        raise cause
    except Exception as cause:
        conn.rollback()
        raise SqlExecutionError("Execution ERR[" + str(cause) +"](" + preparedStmt +")", cause)

    stmt = buildCypher(graphName, cypher, cols)

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute(stmt)
        return cursor
    except SyntaxError as cause:
        conn.rollback()
        raise cause
    except Exception as cause:
        conn.rollback()
        raise SqlExecutionError("Execution ERR[" + str(cause) +"](" + stmt +")", cause)
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We help solve specific problems related to coding , not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what pecific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you why it's done this way but I'll show you why it's different. Also apologies but I'm not used to Python or C.

The `preparedStatement` is calling a custom postgres function `age_prepare_cypher` in this file here `apache/age/src/backend/utils/adt/age_session_info.c`, which calls `set_session_info(graph_name_str, cypher_statement_str);`.

And the `set_session_info` in this file here `apache/age/src/backend/utils/adt/age_session_info.c` just sets it to a global variable `session_info_cypher_statement`.

So your graph name and query are being set in the session.

There's another function that gets your graph name and query back out of the session, and that is the `convert_cypher_to_subquery`. It only gets them out if `is_session_info_prepared()` is true, and only if `graph_name` and `query_str` provided to it are `NULL`.

Seems strange right? But now let's look at this bit of the python `buildCypher` function code:

```
    stmtArr = []
    stmtArr.append("SELECT * from cypher(NULL,NULL) as (")
    stmtArr.append(','.join(columnExp))
    stmtArr.append(");")
    return "".join(stmtArr)
```

It's taking your query and saying your graph name and query string are `NULL`.

So we can conclude that the prepare statement is storing those values in session memory, and then when you execute your statement after using `buildCypher`, it's getting them out of memory and completing the statement again.

I can't explain exactly why or how it does it, but I can see a chunk of test sql in the project that is doing the same sort of thing here:

```
-- should return true and execute cypher command
SELECT * FROM age_prepare_cypher('analyze', 'MATCH (u) RETURN (u)');
SELECT * FROM cypher(NULL, NULL) AS (result agtype);
```

So tl;dr, executing the `prepareStatement` is storing it in session memory, and executing the normal `statement` after running it through buildCypher is grabbing what was just stored in the session.

Answer (score 1):

Building a **Cypher query** involves crafting a query string in the Cypher language to specify graph database operations like pattern matching and filtering. It's the process of defining what you want to do with your data.

**Executing a prepared statement**, on the other hand, takes a pre-built query with placeholders for parameters and sends it to the database for execution. This approach enhances security and performance as it allows for efficient query parsing and execution, with actual parameter values provided at runtime.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34912274)

Answer (score 0):

Both statements perform the same operation.

The difference is that preparedStmt and buildCypher function use different form of cypher queries as shown in code. (cypherStmt & cypher) And their code for building the query is a bit different.