# Why the same query is being executed two times with the two methods?

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

```
def execCypher(conn:ext.connection, graphName:str, cypherStmt:str, cols:list=None, params:tuple=None) -> ext.cursor :
    if conn == None or conn.closed:
        raise _EXCEPTION_NoConnection

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    #clean up the string for modification
    cypherStmt = cypherStmt.replace("\n", "")
    cypherStmt = cypherStmt.replace("\t", "")
    cypher = str(cursor.mogrify(cypherStmt, params))
    cypher = cypher[2:len(cypher)-1]

    preparedStmt = "SELECT * FROM age_prepare_cypher({graphName},{cypherStmt})"
    
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute(sql.SQL(preparedStmt).format(graphName=sql.Literal(graphName),cypherStmt=sql.Literal(cypher)))
    except SyntaxError as cause:
        conn.rollback()
        raise cause
    except Exception as cause:
        conn.rollback()
        raise SqlExecutionError("Execution ERR[" + str(cause) +"](" + preparedStmt +")", cause)

    stmt = buildCypher(graphName, cypher, cols)

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute(stmt)
        return cursor
    except SyntaxError as cause:
        conn.rollback()
        raise cause
    except Exception as cause:
        conn.rollback()
        raise SqlExecutionError("Execution ERR[" + str(cause) +"](" + stmt +")", cause)
```

I just want to understand that if the two execution calls (with preparedStat & buildCypher functions) do the same thing, why are both of them being executed in the same function with same parameters?

Answer (score 0):

The two execution calls are not doing the same thing. `SELECT * FROM age_prepare_cypher({graphName},{cypherStmt})` is just storing the `graphName` and `cypherStmt` into the session.

The `buildCypher` function does this, it doesn't even touch your `cypherStmt`:

```
def buildCypher(graphName:str, cypherStmt:str, columns:list) ->str:
    if graphName == None:
        raise _EXCEPTION_GraphNotSet
    
    columnExp=[]
    if columns != None and len(columns) > 0:
        for col in columns:
            if col.strip() == '':
                continue
            elif WHITESPACE.search(col) != None:
                columnExp.append(col)
            else:
                columnExp.append(col + " agtype")
    else:
        columnExp.append('v agtype')

    stmtArr = []
    stmtArr.append("SELECT * from cypher(NULL,NULL) as (")
    stmtArr.append(','.join(columnExp))
    stmtArr.append(");")
    return "".join(stmtArr)
```

Later on it must be getting the `graphName` and `cypherStmt` back out of the session to use. So it needs both of them to work.

See more at https://stackoverflow.com/a/75461986/6796081